# Copy shapes from one Word document to another

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use one master word document to open multiple slave word documents in a folder, scan each slave for shape objects, or images, and copy from the slave to the master? Here is my sample code.

```
Dim sh as Shape
Path = "C:\users\allwordfiles\"
File = Dir(Path & "*.*")

Do While File <> ""
set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=Path & File)
  
For Each objShape In oDoc.Shapes
  If objShape.InlineShapes.Count > 1 Then

    objShape.InlineShapes.SelectAll 

      Documents("Master.docm").Activate

    objShape.InlineShapes.Paste

  End If      
Next objShape

File = Dir()
```

This code runs, and there is no error, but nothing seems to be selected in any slave document and nothing is copied over to the master document. I feel like something is nit being referenced correctly, but I can't tell what the actual problem really is. Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the path is right? It does not automatically search all sub-folders, and there are probably no files in that folder, even if your user name really is `allwordfiles`.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use AutoText or Building Blocks?

Comment: I used another macro to copy all word files from MANY folders into one folder, so yet all the word files are in one specific folder. I don't know what AutoText or Building Blocks is.

Comment: Given that your code doesn’t copy anything, it isn’t going to paste anything. Images are more likely to be`InlineShapes`. There is no need to `Select` anything. You code will run better if you avoid using `Selection`.

Comment: @Timothy, I just updated my original post with some pseudo code that kind of matches what you described, I think. Does that look close? I'm getting an error on this line: 
If objShapes.InlineShapes.Count > 1

Error Message: Method or Data Member Not Found

Comment: Before you attempt to write another line of code you need to learn how to use: 1) IntelliSense; 2) the Object Browser; 3) online help; 4) Google/Bing. Just making code up and expecting it to work isn't going to get you anywhere.